# Scaled a path without losing its center position

Tags: metapost

```tex
path p ;
p = (1u,1u) -- (1u,3u) -- (3u,3u) -- (3u,1u) -- cycle ;
draw p ;
draw p scaled 2 withcolor red ;
```

The center of the red square is moved from `(2,2)` to `(4,4)` but I want it to stay at `(2,2)`.

[image]

Of course in this example everything is simple, due to the integer factor, and I can just use `shifted -center p`.

[image]

However, life is not as simple as that and with decimal factor this simple trick is not working properly.

```tex
path p ;
p = (1u,1u) -- (1u,3u) -- (3u,3u) -- (3u,1u) -- cycle ;
draw p ;
draw p scaled 1.5 shifted -center p withcolor red ;
```

[image]

So, is it possible to keep the center position of a path when scaling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There may be better ways, but here is one.  The scaling that occurs is about the origin so you can shift to the origin, do your scaling, then shift back.  Your initial attempt worked due to a lucky(?) choice of position and scale factor for the square.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(0);
path p ;
u:=1cm;
p = (1u,1u) -- (1u,3u) -- (3u,3u) -- (3u,1u) -- cycle ;
draw p ;
draw p scaled 1.5 shifted -center p withcolor red ;
draw p shifted -center p scaled 1.5 shifted center p withcolor blue;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]